# Array Implementation in Delphi xe6

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-xe6

I want to fill the last three Edit's with the elements of r. Somehow the value of i is not changing. Please have a look!

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      r: Array of Real;
      cod,h,N,code,i: Integer;
      value: Real;
    begin


      Val(Edit1.Text, cod, code);
      Val(Edit2.Text, h, code);
      Val(Edit3.Text, N, code);

      Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text;
      Edit2.Text := Edit2.Text;
      Edit3.Text := Edit3.Text;
      setlength(r, N);
      i:= 0;
      while i<= N do
         begin

          r[i] := cod/2 + h*i;
          i := i + 1;
        end;

      Edit4.Text := formatfloat('#.0', r[0]);
      Edit5.Text := formatfloat('#.0', r[1]);
      Edit6.Text := formatfloat('#.0', r[2]);
    end;

    end.
```

Comment: The only reason I can see for `i` not changing would be an error reading `N`. I'd probably use StrToInt over val though

Comment: Instead of supply code which refers to GUI controls whose contents we can only guess at, please can you supply an SSCCE with hard coded inputs. Alternatively I commend you to the excellent debugger.

Comment: @JamesBarrass: In this case, TryStrToint would probably even be better, if the result is not ignored. Here, `code` is never checked for errors, it is simply ignored. I also don't understand what `Edit.Text := Edit1.Text` is supposed to do, or why a while loop is used instead of a for loop.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Agreed,I only pointed it out because I saw `Val` used directly so rarely that it took me a moment to realise where `N` was being set.

Comment: @JamesBarrass: Yes, using Val directly is very old school. So is the use of Real. I guess this was taken from a very old example.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is in the shop today.

Comment: The sample contains buggy and useless parts. What is the matter for `N`? Below 3 it will raise an exception and above 3 it is useless (only wasting cpu time). `EditX.Text := EditX.Text;` is useless and hopefully will be eliminated by the compiler (useless code). `Val` did not fill the (local) variable in case of an error (check code) and therefore it remains still undefined and has a random value.

Comment: @all yeah the Edit1.Text := Edit1.Text is useless and the value of N will depend on the number of checkboxes. In this case I just want N to be 3. I tried using a for loop and put the i:=i+1 statement out of the loop but still the output in all the three checkboxes is the same i.e cod/2, no matter what I try i is still zero. Can anyone propose a code for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains a lot of useless and buggy code. So I will fix it as far I can do from the given informations. I added a prefix `L` to all *local* variables

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Lr : Array[0..2] of Real;
  Lcod, Lh : Integer;
  LIdx : Integer;
begin

  // throws an exception if Edit1.Text cannot converted to an Integer
  Lcod := StrToInt( Edit1.Text );
  // throws an exception if Edit2.Text cannot converted to an Integer
  Lh := StrToInt( Edit2.Text );

  for LIdx := 0 to 2 do
    Lr[LIdx] := Lcod/2 + Lh*LIdx;

  Edit4.Text := FormatFloat( '#.0', Lr[0] );
  Edit5.Text := FormatFloat( '#.0', Lr[1] );
  Edit6.Text := FormatFloat( '#.0', Lr[2] );
end;
```

Comment: +1 for prefixing local variable names.  I use a lower case prefix, but I think that was a concession to my camelCase colleagues a long time ago.

Comment: Also, the `Real` datatype has *long* since been deprecated - it currently maps to `double` so that should be used instead.  `Real` was an odd duck 6-byte float type that went out of fashion sometime in the previous century.

Comment: @SirRufo thanks a lot, it works! btw I am new to Delphi and just have some sort of beginner experience in Python, so could you suggest some help guide or something like that? I need to code a whole Winding Model, it would be a big help.
Thanks.

Comment: Real was originally not FPU supported. All FP routines were done in code. Later, it got (optionally) FPU supported (when FPUs became ubiquitous), simply by converting to Double, passing to the FPU and converting the results back to Real48 (as it is called now).